# How to set up if statements so that loop goes forward and then in reverse? Processing

Tags: processing

```js
int x = 31;
int y = 31;

int x_dir = 4;
int y_dir = 0;

void setup ()
{
 size (800, 800); 
}

void draw ()
{
 background (150);
ellipse (x,y,60, 60);


if (x+30>=width)
{
  x_dir =-4;
  y_dir = 4;
}
  if (y+30>=height)
  {
   x_dir=4;
   y_dir = 0;
  }

if (x+30>=width)
{
x_dir = -4;  
}

x+=x_dir;
y+=y_dir;
println(x,y);
}
```

Hi,

I have to create this program in processing which produces an animation of a ball going in a Z pattern (top left to top right, diagonal top right to bottom left, and then straight from bottom left to bottom right) which then goes backwards along the same path it came. 
While I have the code written out for the forward direction, I don't know what 2 if or else statements I need to write for the program so that based on one condition it goes forwards, and based on another condition it will go backwards, and it will continue doing so until it terminates. 
If I am able to figure out which two if statements I need to write, all I need to do is copy and reverse the x_dir and y_dir signs on the forward loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a ton of different ways you can do this.

One approach is to keep track of which "mode" you're in. You could do this using an `int` variable that's `0` when you're on the first part of the path, `1` when you're on the second part of the path, etc. Then just use an `if` statement to decide what to do, how to move the ball, etc.

Here's an example:

```
int x = 31;
int y = 31;

int mode = 0;

void setup ()
{
  size (800, 800);
}

void draw ()
{
  background (150);
  ellipse (x, y, 60, 60);


  if (mode == 0) {
    x = x + 4; 

    if (x+30>=width) {
      mode = 1;
    }
  } else if (mode == 1) {
    x = x - 4;
    y = y + 4;

    if (y+30>=height) {
      mode = 2;
    }
  } else if (mode == 2) {
    x = x + 4;
    if (x+30>=width) {
      mode = 3;
    }
  } else if (mode == 3) {
    x = x - 4;
    y = y - 4;

    if (y-30 < 0) {
      mode = 2;
    }
  }
}
```

Like I said, this is only one way to approach the problem, and there are some obvious improvements you could make. For example, you could store the movement speeds and the conditions that change the mode in an array (or better yet, in objects) and get rid of all of the `if` statements.